# Unity-tweak-tool keep auto remove (Happened Many Times) from 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity-tweak-tool

I installed Unity-Tweak-Tool with command :

> sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool

and changed couple of themes, but now it's no more there in my laptop. I re-installed it. And now it's happening 4th time.

Never experienced such behavior with any other software. Please let me know if I can provide more information.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit).

Here are the results, when I did `ctrl+f` for `remove` keyword in `notepadqq` app for file **:** `/var/log/apt/history.log`.

```
Start-Date: 2017-11-18  03:52:50
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-remove-packages' sender=':1.55'
Remove: unity-webapps-common:amd64 (2.4.17+15.10.20150616-0ubuntu2), webapp-container:amd64 (0.23+16.04.20161028-0ubuntu2), unity-webapps-service:amd64 (2.5.0~+16.04.20160201-0ubuntu1), unity-tweak-tool:amd64 (0.0.7ubuntu2), webbrowser-app:amd64 (0.23+16.04.20161028-0ubuntu2), libunity-webapps0:amd64 (2.5.0~+16.04.20160201-0ubuntu1)
End-Date: 2017-11-18  03:52:56


Start-Date: 2017-11-20  21:09:31
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-remove-packages' sender=':1.84'
Remove: unity-webapps-common:amd64 (2.4.17+15.10.20150616-0ubuntu2), webapp-container:amd64 (0.23+16.04.20161028-0ubuntu2), unity-webapps-service:amd64 (2.5.0~+16.04.20160201-0ubuntu1), unity-tweak-tool:amd64 (0.0.7ubuntu2), webbrowser-app:amd64 (0.23+16.04.20161028-0ubuntu2), libunity-webapps0:amd64 (2.5.0~+16.04.20160201-0ubuntu1)
End-Date: 2017-11-20  21:10:02


Start-Date: 2017-11-20  23:55:21
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-remove-packages' sender=':1.85'
Remove: unity-webapps-common:amd64 (2.4.17+15.10.20150616-0ubuntu2), webapp-container:amd64 (0.23+16.04.20161028-0ubuntu2), unity-webapps-service:amd64 (2.5.0~+16.04.20160201-0ubuntu1), unity-tweak-tool:amd64 (0.0.7ubuntu2), webbrowser-app:amd64 (0.23+16.04.20161028-0ubuntu2), libunity-webapps0:amd64 (2.5.0~+16.04.20160201-0ubuntu1)
End-Date: 2017-11-20  23:55:30


Start-Date: 2017-11-23  12:44:06
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-remove-packages' sender=':1.87'
Remove: unity-webapps-common:amd64 (2.4.17+15.10.20150616-0ubuntu2), webapp-container:amd64 (0.23+16.04.20161028-0ubuntu2), unity-webapps-service:amd64 (2.5.0~+16.04.20160201-0ubuntu1), unity-tweak-tool:amd64 (0.0.7ubuntu2), webbrowser-app:amd64 (0.23+16.04.20161028-0ubuntu2), libunity-webapps0:amd64 (2.5.0~+16.04.20160201-0ubuntu1)
End-Date: 2017-11-23  12:44:16
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you looked thru /var/log/apt/history.log to see what is causing this behavior? (or at least some clues)

Comment: @guiverc I checked that file after you mentioned and searched with "unity-tweak-tool" it's showing how many time I ran this command under Start Date.
Could you please tell me what exactly I should look for ? any specific keyword ??

Thanks

Comment: You should look for the removals. When you find one, edit your question to include the complete output of that session.